# Unable to use bold font in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, font

I want the title of a legend in the print composer to be in bold font. If I change the font to be italic in the item properties font dialog the output becomes italic but if I change it to bold it does not change. I have tried numerous font types.

I am using QGIS 2.18 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I have enabled bold layer names in the print composer settings.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Try to change the font itself. Some fonts do not support bold style.

Comment: I tried numerous font types including typical ones like Arial, Helvetica and  Times New Roman but they all don´t work.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple.
Add your text you need to use as HTML
Use the  bold tag as seen here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_formatting.asp

```
<b> - Bold text
<strong> - Important text
<i> - Italic text
<em> - Emphasized text
<mark> - Marked text
<small> - Small text
<del> - Deleted text
<ins> - Inserted text
<sub> - Subscript text
<sup> - Superscript text
```

And then choose render as html.
You can do some fancy labeling with html. You can even color code each letter of the label as opposed to the label options which act on the whole string